# grabbing value from json array python

Tags: python, json, flask

I am trying to grab values from a json array created by an address formatter for printing labels.

Here is the current code.

```
@app.route('/label', methods=['POST'])
def label():
 if request.method == 'POST':
    rawaddress = request.form['addressraw']
    formatad = usaddress.tag(rawaddress)
    full = json.dumps(formatad)
    return full
```

it returns the data fine.

```
[
 {
    "AddressNumber": "1234", 
    "PlaceName": "New York", 
    "Recipient": "Joe Shmo", 
    "StateName": "New York", 
    "StreetName": "my", 
    "StreetNamePostType": "ave", 
    "ZipCode": "10001"
 }, 
    "Street Address"
]
```

but i am trying to grab values like "AddressNumber" and others to send them to the next step.

I have been scouring anything I can find on it. Normally something like full['AddressNumber'] would work in php, my python is not as good.

Been trying examples from all around the web and SO and still can't figure it out.

Any help would be great!

Comment: What does `usaddress.tag()` do? Assuming it returns a Python `list`, try `formatad[0]["AddressNumber"]`.

Comment: That was it thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json.dumps` returns a string, so `full` is a string.

You should access `formatad[0]['AddressNumber']` for example.

Comment: Wow, so simple. I have been over thinking it like crazy. Thanks man!